# "error" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vee-validate

Using Laravel and vue set up and want to use vee-validate on some forms

I installed via NPM and then added ti my app.js

```
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
```

Also Tried

```
window.VeeValidate = require('vee-validate');
Vue.use(window.VeeValidate);
```

In my component

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
          <input
            v-model="username"
            v-validate="'required|max:16'"
            data-vv-name="username"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="exampleInputEmail1"
            aria-describedby="Username"
          />
          <small>{{error.first('username')}}</small>
        </div>
```

and I get the error

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "error" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validator error object is errors. Hence should be errors and not error.

```
 <small>{{errors.first('username')}}</small>
```

Comment: That's perfect and love it when that happens, thank you

Comment: @GrahamMorbyDev Kindly accept the answer and close the question.

Comment: Oo... You Saved My Life!! Perfect Solution...Thank you..@Riddhi